# C# Auto implemented functions or by force to user implement the functions

Tags: c#, .net

Sample scenario and my first stupid question on this network.

I have `winform` as `dll`.
It's contain reusable `method` and `properties`.

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyWinForm 
{
    public partial class MyWinForm : Form
    {        

    public string SetName{
        get;set;
    }
        public MyWinForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
}
```

Then I used this Form (`MyWinForm`) by removing default `Form` Inheritance code to get `SetName` property for all Windows Forms in My Project.Otherwise I should write that property for all forms in my application.

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FormLogin
{
    public partial class FormLogin: MyWinForm
    { 

        public FormLogin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
}
```

Then I can use `SetName property` in my every and each form by deriving `MyWinForm`.

After That I need to add Method Such as `Save()` ,`Edit()` & `Delete()` to that my custom `MyWinForm` class to user force to implement that methods.How to implement such method with `MyWinForm` class? What concept I use for that?

Objective : When Inherit `MyWinForm` into Other Forms Then Compiler suggest to add That methods into That newly created form.I try to implement Interface,When It's deriving `MyWinForm` that interface method only add in inherited form(MyWinForm).After I inherit `MyWinForm` into Another Form it's not force to implement that methods.I need do that type of things.Because I already Inherited MyWinForm to other Windows Forms.Only I can do change MyWinForm.

**Edit**
[image: C# Auto implemented functions or by force to user implement the functions]

I have custom Winform call `MyWinForm`.It's Then it's Inherits Like this.

```
public partial class FormEployee: MyWinForm
```

Then I am cording with `FormEployee` it's calling from `MDI Form` call **mainForm** menu.
MDI form have four(4) Buttons to call `Save()`,`Edit()`,`Delete()` and `Print()`

It's calling like this.

Ex: Save Button calling in MDI form.Under the save button event I wrote this.

```
 Form activeForm = this.ActiveMdiChild;
```

After that I need to calling something like this.

```
activeForm.Save();
```

**I need declare this `Save()` function in MyParent form.because every active form have save function and it's calling form MDI Parent form.So that function name cannot change.Several developers on this project so I need to have to by force to implement function name same in forms.But method body can change.What type of concept I used to achieve this type of thing?** I try to use C# `Interface` and it's implement my `MyWinForm`.But it's not work.

Comment: I get English may not be your first language but this is not clear to me.  Are you looking for Abstract?

Comment: I can understand ur context but please specify your question more clearly!